# Разграничение прав доступа к таблице для пользователей в Oracle

Tags: oracle

В бд создан пользователь user1. Под ним создана таблица sp_kart с владельцем user1. Необходимо для некоторым пользователей ограничить доступ к этой таблице только чтением. Поэтому был создан новый пользователь user2 и ему даны права только на чтение для таблицы sp_kart.

Проблема в том, что в программе селекты написаны без указания владельца таблицы:

```
select * from sp_kart
```

В итоге при выполнении такого селекта от имени user2 получаю ошибку что такой таблицы нет. Переписывать все селекты в программе на user1.sp_kart не очень хотелось бы. Есть ли способ решить такую пробелму?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Есть 2 варианта, простой - после установки соединения с ораклом первым делом выполните

```
alter session set current_schema=user1
```

Более сложный, на случай если схем несколько или alter сделать не получится: для всех таблиц создайте `public` синонимы:

```
CREATE PUBLIC SYNONYM sp_kart FOR user1.sp_kart
```

Паблик синонимы видят все пользователи, без изменения текущей схемы